# Geomesa Location Indexing Is Not Accurate

Tags: geolocation, geospatial, spatial-index, geomesa

I'm using Geomesa indexing used library for indexing 3D location data (Longitude, Latitude, Time) into 1D indexed data.

Here's my Scala code

```
var z3Indexer = new Z3SFC(TimePeriod.Month);
var z3 = z3Indexer.index(24.664152, 46.692425, 2678400)

var invertedIndex = z3Indexer.invert(z3);
println(invertedIndex._1+" "+invertedIndex._2+" "+invertedIndex._3)
```

The problem is that the deindexed data is not accurate, not like the original data, i need accurate indexing with at least same 6 first digits after decimal point.

Output of the program (deindexed data)

```
24.664232570759083 46.692474695432026 2678400
```

Answer (score 4):

The GeoMesa indexing is a lossy encoding - it is designed to quickly narrow down the search space for querying. As you can see, it's accurate to about 3 decimal places - that is roughly equivalent to [100 meters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_degrees). It's not meant to perfectly encode and decode location data.

Generally, you would use the 1-dimensional index value to narrow your query, then retrieve the exact values stored alongside them.

Answer (score 4):

To expand on Emilio's answer, GeoMesa uses a space-filling curve approach to create a 1-dimensional index for multidimensional data.

This is a 2 step process.  The first step is to pick a number of bits to use in each dimension.  This choice sets the resolution for the curve/index.

As a simple example, suppose that you encoded/indexed longitude/latitudes with only 1 bit of information for each dimension.  This would create 4 cells; each being half a hemisphere.  If this case, all the data in the western half of the north hemisphere would be in the same bucket.

Given a point in this index, there are two operations/questions worth asking.  The first is to ask for the entire bounding box which would cover the point.  The second is to ask for a representative point in the indexed cell.  The 'invert' method you mention is doing the latter.  As an implementation detail, I believe it picks the center of the bounding box.  This is why encoding and inverting a point may 'move' it a little bit.

In order to use this approach in a system like GeoMesa, spatial ranges queries need to look in all the cells covered by the spatial range.  The library code in [GeoMesa](https://github.com/locationtech/geomesa) and [SFCurve](https://github.com/locationtech/sfcurve) are designed to do exactly this.